# Posible Unhandled Promise Rejection Type Error Undefined is not an object

Tags: ios, react-native

Tengo este código en mi proyecto React Native:

```
static async validateSub(sub,pin) {

   sub_can_access = 'no'

   url = 'https://server.com/validator.php'

   let resp = await fetch(url + '?param1='+sub+'&param2='+pin);

   if (resp._bodyText.indexOf("TRUE") >= 0) {

       AsyncStorage.setItem('email', sub)
       AsyncStorage.setItem('password', pin)
       sub_can_access = 'yes'

    } else {

       alert('Try Again');

    }
}
```

El servidor devuelve el texto TRUE Blah Blah Blah. Y en Android funciona bien, pero para iOS, la variable resp viene undefined.

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: 1. Cambias `let resp` para `const resp` por buenas practicas.

Comment: 2. Necesito ver que viene en `resp` con `console.log(resp)` antes de su `if(resp._....`

Comment: 3. Pongas lo que tiene en `fetch(....)` en una nueva variable una linea arriba y hagas debug con `console.log(stringUrl)`, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu proyecto XCode debes habilitar Allow Arbitrary Loads en el info.plist

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]